# Why does my Windows Service built with .net 6.0 and Host.CreateDefaultBuilder fails at startup with DI errors?

Tags: windows-services, .net-6.0

I've spent too long on this not to share.

I made a Windows Service with .Net 6.0 and the `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder` method.  It worked fine, was deployed correctly.  Then I modified something that worked in dev, but failed at startup in prod.

Looking at the logs, there was a problem with Dependency Injection that pointed back to the first line of my `Program.cs`.  I tried everything around every DI thing I injected in the code, all the way to doing an "empty service" that was running a `Task.Delay` loop with nothing injected at all.  It still failed.

I went back with working versions stored in Git.  Still failed.

Nothing changed on the server, *afaik*.

Answer (score 0):

So ultimately, I figured out that the problem was in the bundling of the Publish process: when using `publish as single file`, it failed.  Turning that feature off solved it.

So in your `.csproj`, add (or modify) this line:

```xml
<PublishSingleFile>false</PublishSingleFile>
```

I don't know why it worked at some point and stopped working, but there's definitely something not right with that process.